Antibody self-aggregation: PDB structures
I working on (perhaps more specifically, just worked on) antibody self-aggregation, IgG. So this is where one antibody sticks to the Fc or Fab region of another antibody and so on ... resulting in antibody complexes.
There are experimental data-sets examining self-aggregation, AC-SINS (Affinity-Capture Self-Interacting Nanoparticle Spectroscopy) is one such test and thats cool. However, to make progress on understanding the results I really really need to see a crystal structure, NMR structure etc ... of self-aggregation.
I am having an extremely difficult time navigating PDB attempting to find this.
My request is either:

Does anyone know a PDB code that directly points to my specific request OR
Anyone have advanced insight into navigating the key word database searches on PDB to find this?

I can see antibody structures - about 6000 to 7000 of them. How do I filter this for the few examples required here?

Variable domain mutational analysis to probe the molecular mechanisms of high viscosity of an IgG1 antibody --> 8TJT The Fab fragment of an anti-glucagon receptor (GCGR) antibody

this search for title word "aggragation" ina a subset of PDB ... I guess/hope

Excellent! Thanks @pippo1980 3UPA is just the ticket and https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC10813588/ is cool. Could you provide this answer as a response below? This resolves the issue as well as I could have hoped (slightly better to be honest). Note to mods, please do not delete these comments! until they are formal answers.

As per google search:
Variable domain mutational analysis to probe the molecular mechanisms of high viscosity of an IgG1 antibody  paper :

......Here, we combined X-ray crystallography with computational modeling to predict regions of an anti-glucagon receptor (GCGR) IgG 1 antibody prone to self-interaction...

that points to  ---> 8TJT The Fab fragment of an anti-glucagon receptor (GCGR) antibody 
or using this database: SAbDab (The Structural Antibody Database) , citation Dunbar, J., Krawczyk, K. et al (2014). Nucleic Acids Res. 42. D1140-D1146

SAbDab is a database of antibody structures that updates on a weekly basis. Each structure is annotated with a number of properties including experimental details, antibody nomenclature (e.g. heavy-light pairings), curated affinity data and sequence annotations.
Use the database to:
Inspect individual structures
Create and download datasets for analysis
Search the database for structures with similar sequences to your query
Monitor the known structural repetoire of antibodies
SAbDab has been built by the Oxford Protein Informatics Group (OPIG) under an open-innovation agreement.
If you use our tools, please cite our paper: Dunbar, J., Krawczyk, K. et al (2014). Nucleic Acids Res. 42. D1140-D1146 [link]

and searching the database with the option Search structures by attribute and  keyword query  using keyword  "aggregation"  in title
you get these results:
pdb
8cpe
7nxx
3upc
3upc
5lwf
4m3j
3upa
1ohq
4n1h

and as per comments above 3UPA seems to be a good candidate: Variable domain mutational analysis to probe the molecular mechanisms of high viscosity of an IgG1 antibody

Thanks @pippo1980 much appreciated. To other site members please upvote this response, it's really helpful. 3UPA is certainly cool.
